# Can I count text as another category using TeXCount?

Tags: macros, texcount

I am using [TeXCount](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/) to perform a word count. I am using `%TC:macro \macroname n` (http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/faq.html#newmacro) to treat macros differently (for example I have a 'to-do' macro). Can I count the contents of these macros and put this count in a custom category for HTML output? Their `other` option ("count text as other text") puts the count in the same category as captions, etc. which is undesired.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{minimal}
\newcommand\todo[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\todo{Insert some text here.}
\end{document}
```

Given a 'to-do' macro `todo` which simply colours the enclosed text in red, I seek a TeXCount command like `%TC:macro \todo [my_category]` which counts the number of words enclosed in `\todo` and associates it with `my_category`. It should produce something like the following.

```
File: mwe.tex
Encoding: ascii
Words in text: 0
Words in headers: 0
Words outside text (captions, etc.): 0
Number of headers: 0
Number of floats/tables/figures: 0
Number of math inlines: 0
Number of math displayed: 0
Number of words in my_category: 4
Subcounts:
  text+headers+captions (#headers/#floats/#inlines/#displayed/#my_category)
0+0+0 (0/0/0/0/4) _top_
```

I appreciate that this may not be possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your question and welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you please edit your post and add fully compilable (minimum working) example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))? It would be a fine starting point for the solvers.

Comment: I do something not entirely unlike this. In my case, I remove some extra text and count the number of occurrences of a particular kind of macro created in the preamble. It would be straightforward to adapt this to get a word count of specific parts of the text. The way I do it involves creating a temporary file and feeding that to `texcount`. Essentially you would create two such files and give counts for each. I use a script which wraps `texcount` and does all this automatically. The details depend on your code and OS, though. But that's the basic strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a recent version of TeXcount (version 3), you can add more counters and use these to count words.

```
%TC:newcounter mine My words
%TC:macro \mytext [mine]
Text inside \mytext{my macro} now gets counted separately.
```

The syntax of `newcounter` is

```
%TC:newcounter _name_ _description_
```

where the description may consist of several words (i.e. may contain space) and will be used as as the counter description in the summary.

I guess the TeXcount FAQ could do with an update...